# Biztalk Send Pipeline Properties set through Admin Console are not being set

Tags: biztalk, pipeline, custom-component, biztalk-pipelines

I have a Receive location with both Rcv as well as a Send pipeline.
Both the pipelines have a Custom Pipeline component that has some Design-Time properties.
In the Send pipeline, if I am setting those properties through BizTalk Admin Console, the properties are not being overridden. However, the same thing works completely fine with Rcv pipeline.
I cannot just set the properties at Design time as it is an Environment based value and need to be set at runtime.

Comment: Is it the same Component on both Ports?

Comment: Both pipelines have the same components? Is any component after your custom component?

Comment: Yes, both the components are exactly the same. And yes, there is another custom component after the pipeline component in question.

Comment: Can you share with us the relevant code from your pipeline component?   At what stage in the pipeline is it for the Receive and the Send?   At what point in the send are you looking for the properties, in another pipeline component or a map?

Answer (score 0):

*After debugging the pipeline component, this is what I have found:*

Following is the usual working of a Pipeline component (http://geekswithblogs.net/cyoung/archive/2011/09/14/biztalk-server-2010-loading-properties-in-custom-pipeline-components.aspx)

When a pipeline component is executed, the Load method of Pipeline components is called twice - first time it loads all the design time properties set on the Pipeline and when the Load method is called the second time, it is loading the Property Bag as set in the Pipeline configuration on BizTalk Admin Console.
**Note:** Only the properties that are changed will be passed in this property bag.

When we use a Request-Response Receive location, the above mentioned process is followed on the Receive Pipeline.However, when the same pipeline component is called from the Send pipeline,the Load method is only called once and hence none of the properties set from the BizTalk Admin Console are being set and the design-time properties do not get overwritten, thus causing the issue.

I have found a similar post witht he similar issue and no answer(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c69b3af1-b208-4213-884e-a98b8583761c/strange-ipersistpropertybag-load-pattern?forum=biztalkgeneral)

It looks like it is by design and I will be raising a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: Hi. I do not agree with your results :) At first I had the same problem as you but after restarting the IIS application pool the run time properties are loaded just fine. Please give me more information about your setup!

My setup is as follows: Request-Response receive location of type WCF-CustomIsolated. In the Validate stage of the Receive Pipeline I have a simple string replacement component. The same component is used in the Encode stage of the Send Pipeline. (To get the response back I have a WCF-Custom loopback send-port but I don't think this is relevant for the problem).

Comment: ...and I tested this on BT2013 with CU6 installed.

Comment: Hi, my setup is as follows:

I have a Request-Response Receive location with a WCF-BasicHttp adapter.
i am using the custom pipeline component in the decode stage of the Rcv pipeline and Encode stage of the Send pipeline.
I have tried restarting IIs App pools but it did not solve anything.

Comment: Strange. If you are willing to share the pipeline-component code with me I could test it out on my box. At the very least it would be interesting to see the Load and Save methods, and the declaration of your properties.

Comment: public virtual void Load(IPropertyBag pb, int errlog)   
{ 
 object val = null;
 val = this.ReadPropertyBag(pb, "ConnectionString");
 if ((val != null))
 this.ConnectionString = ((string)(val));
}
  
private object ReadPropertyBag(IPropertyBag pb, string propName)
{  object val = null;
try 
 { 
 pb.Read(propName, out val, 0);
 }
 catch (System.ArgumentException)
 {
  return val;
 }
 catch (System.Exception e)
 {
  throw new System.ApplicationException(e.Message);
 }
 return val;
}

Comment: public virtual void Save(Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPropertyBag pb, bool fClearDirty, bool fSaveAllProperties)
{this.WritePropertyBag(pb, "ConnectionString", this.ConnectionString);}

private void WritePropertyBag(Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPropertyBag pb, string propName, object val)
{
 try
 {pb.Write(propName, ref val);
 catch (System.Exception e)
 {
  throw new System.ApplicationException(e.Message);
 }
}

Comment: Everything works for me, using your code. I will drop this now. I would recommend simplifying your integration until you have pinpointed the exact problem. For example: Remove all other pipeline components, simplify the code in the pipeline component you are having problems with. Good luck and please return to this question with the answer once you have found out what the problem was.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you have restarted the host after you made the design time change. Also, you can put a break point also to see how it is behaving.

Comment: I have restarted the Host instances. It does not help. I will debug the solution and post my findings here.